# Parsing a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 46 rows where each row is of the following format.

`{‘duration': 30.0, 'spot_per_kwh': -4.86251, 'per_kwh': 17.62777, 'date': datetime.date(2022, 10, 31), 'nem_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 31, 0, 30, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 36000)), 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 30, 14, 0, 1, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'end_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 30, 14, 30, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'renewables': 111.078, 'channel_type': <ChannelType.GENERAL: 'general'>, 'spike_status': <SpikeStatus.NO_SPIKE: 'none'>, 'descriptor': <Descriptor.EXTREMELY_LOW: 'extremelyLow'>, 'type': 'ActualInterval'}`

Each element of the row is a combination of a column heading.Eg 'duration' and  value 30.0. How can I parse this dataframe so the resulting output is as follows:

```
duration.....spot_per_kwh.....per_kwh etc
```

..30.0...................-4.86251....................17.62777

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [Dataframe.from_record](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_records)

Comment: That is a python dictionary in a single column? Perhaps [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)? As for question writing, smaller examples are better. How about posting a script that initializes a dataframe of 2 rows and only a few samples of your data? And in the "what you want" section, the `....` are very confusing. You want dots? Is this a display you want or are you trying to get dataframe columns?

Comment: @hide1nbush this has the correct data format in an example. But unfortunetly has no effect on the dataframe in question. Thanks for posting.

Comment: "has no effect" - that's not possible. `pd.DataFrame.from_records` will either create a DataFrame or raise an error. If it's raising an error, feel free to post the error traceback you're getting so we can help. As your question currently stands, it's not reproducible - this is just a single dictionary. Wrapped in a list, this would work fine - the error would have to come from conflicting formats across rows.

Comment: @ tdelaney

import pandas as pd
list_val = pd.read_csv('alist.csv', sep= ',  ', engine ='python')
this_try =  pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_val)

The dot are a ham fisted way of getting the columns to line up - sorry. Using the tab, tabs out of the box.